# How can I include columns from a relational table inside an entity without getting "missing column" errors on my lists?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Say I have 3 related tables: “company”, “worker” and “skills”. A company can have many workers and the workers can have many skills. The company to worker relation is done through a company_worker_id, and the skills table has a worker_id column which store the same ID as the worker_id column in the workers table.

Great, now I would like to create a list on the frontend that shows a list of workers and their skills when a company is picked.

So first I create a public interface that extends to the skills entity and joins all three tables

```
public interface SkillRepository extends JpaRepository<Skills, UUID> {
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = """
                    select
                        UUID() id,
                        s.*,
                        w.name worker_name
                    from
                        worker w
                        INNER JOIN skills s ON w.id = s.worker_id
                    where
                       w.id = s.worker_id
                       AND w.company_id = :companyId
        """)
List<skills> getSkillsAndWorkers(UUID companyId);
}
```

Great.

Now here comes the tricky part. In order for worker_name to show up when I output the data on the frontend, I need to add it as a column in the skills entity file, like so:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "skills") 
@public class Skills {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;
    
    @Column(name = "worker_id")
    private UUID workerId;
    
    @Column(name = "worker_name")
    private String workerName;
}
```

This of course works, BUT the skills entity is used for other lists in the system, so when I add worker_name to that file, the other lists will crash and I will get a warning that the column “worker_name” is missing, which is obvious because it is not used in any other lists than the one which is using the “getSkillsAndWorkers” query.

I know that I COULD just do an inner join and add worker_name to every other query I have in the system, but there must be a different way to handle this.

So my question is: How can I include the worker_name column from the worker entity inside the skills entity without messing up every other list in the system that uses the skills entity without the worker data?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the query to return a Skill DTO.
See how to do it here https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries/

Another option is to return the Worker entity, and each worker has a list of Skill.